# Binding Text Descriptions to TextBoxes

Tags: c#, wpfdatagrid

I have a problem using C# and WPF of binding Text to TextBoxes in a Grid.  The binding actually works, except that it doesn't show up on the UI until I double click in the TextBox to edit.  Then the text fills in.  I'm using DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate.  I've noticed that if I just use CellTemplate, the data fills in (but obviously I can't change it).  Can anyone tell me what must be different?  I'll post code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to bind a text column then you can do this.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
```

If you have something more complicated in mind with a DataGridTemplateColumn, then you may need a to specify a CellTemplate and a CellEditingTemplate.  You'll need to describe what your trying to do, and show the Xaml.